# React Native warning - cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks in the componentWillUnmount

Tags: reactjs, react-native, fetch

Since my app is fetching images from API and rendering the result as expected. But showing this warning is incomplete to this project and given answers aren't solved out my issue.

Moreover, it couldn't be solved with AbortController to pass the signal as a parameter in fetch call and using `AbortController.abort()` in `componentWillUnmount`

```
Warning: Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component. 
This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application. 
To fix, cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks in the componentWillUnmount 
method.
```

CODE:

```
componentDidMount() {
    this.getImage(Flikr_URL);
  }

  getImage(url) {
    fetch(url)
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(responseJson =>
        this.setState({
          imageData: responseJson.photos.photo,
          loading: false
        })
      )
      .catch(err => {
        console.log(err);
        throw error;
      });
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    this.getImage();
  }
```

Someone advice would really save my day.

Comment: Why do you call `this.getImage()` in your `componentWillUnmount()`?

Comment: @tkausl could you explain how to resolve this issue?